# Yellow flickering exclamation mark appears on onion icon in toolbar when opening a new web page

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Can anyone tell me what it means? I suppose it's some kind of warning, but it doesn't say what for. I get it every time I open a new web page; then, choosing 'Preferences'-->'Restore Defaults' from the menu that opens when the icon is clicked on, it goes away, but it comes back every time I open a new web page. Can I make it disappear permanently? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The flickering exclamation mark shows you that a new release of Tor Browser is available. It is a recommendation to download the new version. So the best way to get rid of it is to go to https://torproject.org/ and to download the new Tor Browser Bundle.